# How to add Laravel 5.2/ Laravel 5.3 onto Google App Engine?

Tags: laravel, google-app-engine, laravel-5

I would like to make a php backend for my app using Laravel framework. What are the steps involved to setup Laravel onto Google App Engine which I am planning to use as a server.

UPDATE: As of 24th March, 16. Laravel 5.2 cannot be integrated with google app engine because of an error as discussed in this issue raised in gitHub. https://github.com/shpasser/GaeSupportL5/issues/45

Comment: this guy seems to have gotten it to work https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1da6sSm-tGbGsv3fYbqkmc8Vg6ooRdKmjL4JpkDz9x0Q/edit#slide=id.g13003651de_0_23

Comment: this talks about laravel 5.1 ... not laravel 5.2

Comment: Since the answer is that only Laravel 5.1 will work on App Engine for now, until issue #45 is resolved, please consider posting this as a self-answer so this question can be closed and the community can be informed.

Comment: @Adam, I am not following developments with neither app engine nor laravel. So if finally someone develops such a tool/ provides a solution then I would like to mark that as correct answer. Otherwise I have added the current status in the question itself

Comment: Fair enough, but the point of Stack Overflow is to provide answers to questions, and an answer that something is a bug, is not working, or is not possible is still a valid answer. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261168/is-this-is-not-possible-an-acceptable-answer/261186.

Comment: I'll adhere to the accepted answer in the link you provided `If you can actually demonstrate that something is impossible (as opposed to simply not knowing how to do it), then go ahead and post it as an answer.`.

I cannot demonstrate that it cannot be done and I do not know how to do it. So it makes no sense that I put the bug as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use [Google Container Engine](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/)?

You can build a container (Docker is a good choice in my opinion) with PHP and Laravel.

Comment: Does this actually work? Is there a tutorial of this somewhere? Seems like the complications associated with Laravel on GCE are more complex than just composing it.

Comment: There is a way for laravel > 5.4 https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-flexible